# chrome developer mode style sidebar linked css no more

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In my Google Chrome version 38.0.2125.104, stylesheet filename/linked css has been disappeared. I'm not sure if updated version removed this or there is somewhere to set this up again, but when i restored to default, still it does not appear.

To make it clear to you guys, This is an example of old version Style Panel which have the link to the related stylesheet (filename & line) next to the class name.

http://i.pictr.com/7g52x66rw8.png (i cant attach images here yet)

and below is the latest Style Panel. Each classes usually have link to the CSS stylesheet .

http://i.pictr.com/sks0tp1sem.png

Any idea on how to enable back the stylesheet link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when you open the inspect element on the top right side of the dev eloper tools panel you have a cog wheel (settings). click that and go to general setting s tab and check out the elements section and sources section and see if all the boxes that needs to be checked are checked.... in mine i have the source maps box checked and enabled

Comment: i have chrome Version 38.0.2125.104 m and I have the link to the css or js source maps in my dev tools.